# Rename all files in a folder using batch

Tags: batch-file, directory, rename, renaming

I would like to create a batch file to rename all the files with extension ".log" in a folder to append with today's date.

For example :

App.log will be appended to App.log06112010
where date is 06112010.

Please suggest

Comment: Possibly better answered on ServerFault?

Comment: @ Pekka : Thanks for the suggestion.

@ glowcoder : This is on Windows server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
forfiles /m *.log /c "cmd /c ren @file @file06112010"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
export TODAYSDATE=`date "+%m%d%Y"`

umask 000
for filename in $1
do
  if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
    echo "$filename doesn't exist!"
  else
    if [ -d $1 ]; then
      echo "Skipping directory $filename..."
    else
      mv $filename $filename$TODAYSDATE
    fi
  fi
done
```

Usage: `move.sh "*.log"`