# Renaming file by its name and date using batch file 

Tags: file, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that renames all the files in the folder by its name concatenate underscore and date.For example if there is a file name is >User1 so it will be >User1_25072012. I found a code which changes all the file name by date but not by the name and the date as in the example above.

So could you please show me a way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026007/rename-all-files-in-a-folder-using-batch

Comment: Thanks Thinhbk, I have read that one before which the user want the file to be in .log type. I wanted to be in every type. I am new to these batch types.

Comment: Did you try: Usage: move.sh "*.*" as in above solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
@echo off
cd "C:\account folder"
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ('echo %date%') do set today=%%a%%b%%c
for %%f in (*.*) do ren "%%f" "%%~nf_%today%%%~xf"
```

Comment: Thanks Bali. How can I specify this code for C:\account folder etc? Thanks.

Comment: NP. I have edited my answer so it will do this, just change the folder name to the folder you need to use this in. Just remember to put quotes around it if the path has spaces.

Comment: Thanks again Bali. It works but it changes the file type to. How can I prevent that please?

Comment: It should leave the filetype the same, what does it change it to?

Comment: Sorry, I have just seen the problem, it should be fixed now, try my updated answer.

Comment: It change it to ( 2012 ) file type . Also is there a way to show the created day date insteade of today date? Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14398/discussion-between-bali-c-and-luai-kalkatawi)