# How to use a Batch-File to Rename a File to Include the Date?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I've got a text file that displays an alarm printer. I would like to set up a batch file, under Windows XP, to change the default name of the alarm printer to include the date, which would make searching for errors much easier. The alarm printer is captured to a text file.

I've been able to change the name, but every time I try to set the name to the date either nothing happens or the name is changed to the code instead.

So far I've tried

```batch
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ "%d in (%date%) do rename "C:\TPM 4 Alarm Printer\test.txt" %%e-%%f-%%g.txt
```

and

```batch
for /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date/t') do set y=%%k
for /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date/t') do set d=%%k%%i%%j
for /F "tokens=5-8 delims=:. " %%i in ('echo.^| time ^| find "current" ') do set t=%%i%%j
set t=%t%_ if "%t:~3,1%"=="_"
set t=0%t% set t=%t:~0,4%
set "C:\Users\e727896\Desktop\test.txt=%d%%t%"
echo %C:\Users\e727896\Desktop\test.txt% –
```

Comment: What operating system? Linux / Windows / Mac? Give us some informations about the files names... example?

Comment: I've tried: for /f "tokens"1-5 delims=/"%d in (%date%) do rename "C:\TPM 4 Alarm Printer\test.txt" %%e-%%f-%%g.txt

Comment: I've tried: for /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date/t') do set y=%%k
for /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date/t') do set d=%%k%%i%%j
for /F "tokens=5-8 delims=:. " %%i in ('echo.^| time ^| find "current" ') do set t=%%i%%j
set t=%t%_
if "%t:~3,1%"=="_" set t=0%t%
set t=%t:~0,4%
set "C:\Users\e727896\Desktop\test.txt=%d%%t%"
echo %C:\Users\e727896\Desktop\test.txt%

Comment: Forgot the OS. Using a Windows XP desktop

Comment: I've got a text file that displays an alarm printer. I would like to set up a batch file to change the default name of the alarm printer to include the date, which would make searching for errors much easier. The alarm printer is captured  to a text file.

Comment: Possibly Related questions: [Renaming file by its name and date using batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11648499/2712809) and [Rename all files in a folder using batch](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3026007/2712809)

Answer (score 7):

This will provide a more reliable timestamp if you are using XP Pro.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%"
set "Min=%dt:~10,2%"
set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%
set timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%
set fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%

ren "C:\TPM 4 Alarm Printer\test.txt" "Alarm - %fullstamp%.txt"
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like this should work on XP :

```dos
ren "C:\TPM 4 Alarm Printer\test.txt" "%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%.txt"
```

Just adapt it for your problem.