# Renaming a file within a batch file to the date as YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, format, rename

Basically, I manually rename a bunch of zip files to the date every week or so and it takes a long time as there are 25+ (they are backups of various sorts).

I wanted to create a batch file that can rename them for me. The files are called 'latest.zip'.

I have tried many ways to do it, but the closest I have gotten that actually works was by using 'ren latest.zip %DATE:/-%.zip'. The issue with this is that it gives me the date as DDMMYYYY with no '-'s and is in the wrong order, such as 05122015 for today.

How would I make it so the file would be named 2015-12-05 (for today)?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: you talk about .bat file?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a Batch-File to Rename a File to Include the Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895422/how-to-use-a-batch-file-to-rename-a-file-to-include-the-date)

Comment: `for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%date%") do ren latest.zip %%c-%%b-%%a.zip`

Comment: I just get %%a was unexpected at this time? Any ideas?

Comment: Your question said: "Renaming a file **within a batch file**...". Did you put previous line _in a batch file_? For further details, type `for /?` at the command prompt.

Comment: as @Aacini said you have to use `%%a` in a batch file, but use `%a` (only one percentage sign) in the commandline.